# how to combine multipe if's in google spreadsheet

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, excel-formula

I made a single formula and use 4 cells, but I want to combine then into 1 cell. Everything I tried didn't work. So I hope you can help me out please.

My problem to solve is how do I get the 4 single formula combined into cell B12 only. Without using the other cells B13,B14,B15

```
=if($A$12<B23;B23*C23)             
    =if($A$12<B24;B24*C24)
        =if($A$12<B25;B25*C25)
            =if($A$12<B26;B26*C26)

**expample problem:**
   =if(A12<B23,A12*C23,if(A12<B24,a12*C24,if(A12<B25,B25*C25,if(A12<B26,B26*C26,"Problems"))))
```

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bw94jd4bf92JTjdKSUdvT3cwcTA

with kindly regards

Comment: At the moment, your if expressions only evaluate if true; you should ideally build them to be '=if(condition,valuewhentrue,valuewhenfalse)'

Comment: thnx for the comment,

Comment: What is the precedence here? ie. If A12 is less than B23 AND B24, do you want to return A12*C23 or A12*C24?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to want something similar to this:

```
=IF($A$12 < B23, $A$12 * C23, IF($A$12 < B24, $A$12 * C24, IF($A$12 < B25, $A$12 * C25, IF($A12 < B26, $A$12 * C26, $A$12))))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was what i was looking for the final formula =        =IF($A$12>B23;$A$12*C23;IF($A$12<B23;$A$12*C23;IF($A$12<B24;$A$12*C24;IF($A$12<B25;$A$12*C25;IF($A12<B26;$A$12*C26;$A$12;IF($A12>B26;$A$12*C26;$A$12))))))